# Can't I assign values from a $().attr() in the same line?

Tags: jquery, selector, image, src, attr

I'm trying to do this:

```
$('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
    $("mainproductpicture").attr("src") = $("smallpictureone").attr("src");
});
```

`#mainproductpicture` is the bigger picture on my page. So when someone clicks on the smaller one, the src of that smaller one should be set to the bigger picture.

Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[jQuery's attr() function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) uses the following syntax**:

```
$('yourselector').attr('attribute','value');
```

**For your purposes, using `this` may also help:**

```
$('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
    $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

**There was also a # missing the the selector for mainproductpicture:**

`$("mainproductpicture")` *should be* `$("#mainproductpicture");`

Comment: I like your answer better because it uses `$(this)` which is a neat trick that's good to know.

Comment: It makes things a bit easier to read and you'll find you use it quite often :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

change:

```
 $("mainproductpicture").attr("src") = $("smallpictureone").attr("src");
```

to:

```
 $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $("#smallpictureone").attr("src"));
```

[jQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) takes an optional second parameter for the value to set that attribute. And it seems you forgot to add your `#` in the event handler IDs

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value as the second parameter to the attr method. You also need to use the # symbol (assuming they are ids)...

```
$('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
    $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $("#smallpictureone").attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should add the selectors, # or .

```
$('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
    $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src") = $("#smallpictureone").attr("src");
});
```

But I guess that was just a typo, or not?

Secondly, it has to be in this form:

attr( attributeName, value  )

```
$('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
    $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#smallpictureone').click(function () {
    $("#mainproductpicture").attr("src",$("#smallpictureone").attr("src"));
});
```